# What is the meaning of "highway shops"?

Tags: meaning, etymology

I was curious what the meaning of "highway shops" is.
It's related to the software industry, but I could not find much information about it. Also, I only found it being used in 2 places.

From this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411660/enterprise-library-unity-vs-other-ioc-containers):

> Great library for Microsoft or the highway shops.

And also on this [site](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2688270):

> Some places are MS-or-the-highway shops...

Any information on the meaning or etymology would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Highway shop* is not specifically a software term; however, *shop* means a place of software development.

The two responses cited are making a play on the aphorism:

> [My way or the highway.](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/my_way_or_the_highway)

The hyphenation of the second quote indicates that it is using the aphorism. The intended meaning would be:

> Some businesses are Microsoft-only shops, with no possibility of using a non-Microsoft technology stack.